# getting Connection reset by peer exception (toplink)

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, spring-mvc, jdbc, toplink

I am using the following code to ensure that the file contents are written successfully to disk

```
public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target, int count) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;     
    if (target != null) {
        try {
            if (!target.exists()) {
                target.createNewFile();
                if (source == null) {
                    return; 
                } else {    
                    in = source.openStream();   
                }
                out = new FileOutputStream(target);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }               
                log.debug("The contents from the URL: " + source + " are successfully written to the file " + target);              
                //add for successfull
            } else {
                log.debug("skipping creation of asset");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            if(count < 3){   
                if (in != null) {   
                    in.close(); 
                }
                if (out != null) {  
                     out.close();   
                }

                // Attempt to delete it
                boolean success = target.delete();  
                if (!success) { 
                    log.debug("Unable to delete " + target);    
                } else {    
                    copyFileFromUrl(source, target, ++count);   
                }    
            } else {    
                log.debug(e.getClass().getName());
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }    
        } finally { 
            if (in != null) {   
                in.close(); 
            }
            if (out != null) {  
                 out.close();   
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this code like this

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    CourseMaterials cm = iter.next();       
    String url;
    try {
        Asset asset = cm.getAsset();
        List<AssetVersion> av = asset.getAssetVersions();

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        log.debug("Bad asset so skipping...");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }

    ....

    try {
        URL earl = new URL(visualElementURL);
        scormFileWriter.copyFileFromUrl(earl, new File(absoluteFileName), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now how i am trying is like, When i come to function `copyFileFromUrl()`, i unplug the cable, it tries two times, then on third time i plug in the cable. The function returns successfully. As i am in while loop. Now after that when i come to line

```
Asset asset = cm.getAsset();
```

I get `Connection Reset by peer exception`. It skips this asset and then again it starts normally. Why ? Why i am getting `connection Reset by peer exception` ? If i am getting this exception because of unplug the cable then i should get it for all other assets also, but i am getting this exception only for the next iteration, then it starts working fine, i mean then line `Asset asset = cm.getAsset();` throws no exception after throwing first time?

Why this is happening? How can i overcome it?

I am using SQL server 2008 for database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try using flush() method before close() method